# What is the meaning of 'components' in principal component regression?

Tags: r, pca

I'm learning principal component regression and I don't understand the result I get from PCR method. My goal of using PCR is to reduce the number of predictors.

For example:

```
library(caret)
# Load the data
data("Boston", package = "MASS")
# Split the data into training and test set
set.seed(123)
training.samples <- Boston$medv %>%
  createDataPartition(p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
train.data  <- Boston[training.samples, ]
test.data <- Boston[-training.samples, ]
# Build the model on training set
set.seed(123)
model <- train(
  medv~., data = train.data, method = "pcr",
  scale = TRUE,
  trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10),
  tuneLength = 10
  )

# Print the best tuning parameter ncomp that
# minimize the cross-validation error, RMSE
summary(model)

model$bestTune
```

I get:

```
Data:   X dimension: 407 13 
    Y dimension: 407 1
Fit method: svdpc
Number of components considered: 5
TRAINING: % variance explained
          1 comps  2 comps  3 comps  4 comps  5 comps
X           47.48    58.40    68.00    74.75    80.94
.outcome    38.10    51.02    64.43    65.24    71.17
```

and

```
  ncomp
5     5
```

1. May I ask what does 1 comps...5 comps means?
2. What does theresult ncomp 5 from model$bestTune mean?
3. Where can I find the reduced model from those results? (My final goal is to select essential predictors.)

Thanks.

-C.T

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read about PCR, it's useful for dimensionality reduction, especially given collinearity between the variables. Some useful links:

http://www.milanor.net/blog/performing-principal-components-regression-pcr-in-r/

http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2016/05/pcr_part1_xonly/

The model fitting procedure you performed is not telling you which of the original variables to use for prediction, but rather suggesting various ways of combining *all* the variables using different sets of coefficients to come up with a shorter list of meta-predictors, or "components."

`summary(model)` is telling you that using a single component can help explain 38% of the outcome, but using 5 components will explain 71%. (Which is judged by `bestTune` to be the best balance between predictive power and model simplicity.)

To see what these components look like, you can look at `model[["finalModel"]][["coefficients"]]`, output copied below. I believe this is showing the coefficient that is applied to a standardized version of each variable to create each of the first few components.

```
, , 1 comps   # coefficients applied to variables to create component #1

            .outcome
crim    -0.592587562
zn       0.599992485
indus   -0.802349361
chas     0.006248825
nox     -0.791459829
rm       0.447008384
age     -0.713823494
dis      0.739724065
rad     -0.741112634
tax     -0.785801427
ptratio -0.487355792
black    0.457723689
lstat   -0.716345800

, , 2 comps    # coefficients applied to variables to create component #2...

          .outcome
crim    -1.3071490
zn      -0.1696660
indus   -0.5509926
chas     1.3404699
nox     -0.1278061
rm       1.2483213
age      0.2066896
dis     -0.2710928
rad     -1.3575348
tax     -1.3611397
ptratio -1.5186875
black    0.8599876
lstat   -1.0065236

, , 3 comps

            .outcome
crim    -0.379353935
zn       0.914275307
indus   -0.663750247
chas     1.800225620
nox      0.173805923
rm       2.911531130
age      0.006938608
dis     -0.221098241
rad     -0.348203175
tax     -0.583374313
ptratio -2.388449513
black   -0.232188538
lstat   -1.784086797

, , 4 comps

          .outcome
crim    -0.4650669
zn       0.8355077
indus   -0.6614445
chas     1.0473459
nox      0.3090320
rm       3.0563403
age      0.1453604
dis     -0.3965918
rad     -0.4828702
tax     -0.6739500
ptratio -2.6654286
black   -0.3997876
lstat   -1.8464750

, , 5 comps

           .outcome
crim    -0.56682510
zn       0.07089925
indus   -0.72683562
chas     0.61226427
nox      0.03060117
rm       4.18612272
age      0.17409947
dis     -0.70519697
rad      0.11136186
tax     -0.31640619
ptratio -1.42839422
black    0.70692195
lstat   -2.80938875

, , 6 comps

          .outcome
crim    -0.4526589
zn       0.2148831
indus   -0.7151197
chas     0.5618245
nox      0.0850809
rm       4.1544127
age      0.2220764
dis     -0.7142467
rad      0.1485075
tax     -0.2614366
ptratio -1.5666266
black    1.0166062
lstat   -2.7407352
```

Comment: May I ask how can I use pcr to perform variable selection? Base on your results of each components, it seems like every component uses all variables in dataset (without selection). I'm wondering whether pcr() can do the same thing as glmnet () does (tell me what variables in dataset are most important). Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it is most useful for variable selection. http://www.milanor.net/blog/performing-principal-components-regression-pcr-in-r/   "PCR is not a feature selection method because each of the calculated principal components is a linear combination of the original variables. Using principal components instead of the actual features can make it harder to explain what is affecting what."